# Ember-data transforms aren't applying with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Project setup:

- Ember: 2.0.0
- Ember-data: 2.0.0
- Ember-cli: 1.13.8

I have created a transform:
transforms/isodate.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({

    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        serialized = window.moment(serialized).toDate();
        if(serialized.toString() === "Invalid Date"){serialized = null}
        return serialized;
    },

    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        deserialized = window.moment(deserialized).toISOString();
        return deserialized;
    }
});
```

and used it like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    Forename: DS.attr('string'),
    Surname: DS.attr('string'),
    Gender: DS.attr('string'),
    DOB: DS.attr('isodate'),
});
```

But the transform is not being applied.

I get no error messages, and breakpoints in the transform aren't being fired. I have tested this with a new transform called `foo`, and I get the exact same behaviour, the transform is not being called.

Has something changed in ember 2.0 that hasn't been updated on the docs that would result in the above not working?

Comment: Unfortunately Transforms don't seem to be working at all. I created a test transform that just appended 'foo' to the string and it did nothing.

Comment: transform functions are not fired? check transform file name

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You mean check that the file name matches the data type passed to my data attribute? If so, as I said I have created a test transform with a totally different file name ('foo.js') and it didn't get called.

Comment: I mean just check it's 'transforms/isodate.js'.

Comment: What do you mean by "But the transform is not being applied"? You got error message or what's wrong?

Comment: No error message, the Transformer just isn't being applied to attributes set to that data type. In fact I get no errors if I try to set the attribute type to gibberish (not sure if ember gives errors for non existent Transforms).

Comment: What is the file name of your transform?

Comment: isodate.js inside of the transforms dir generated by ember-cli

Answer (score 0):

Transforms still work with ember-cli 2.0+, here is one I am using right now in my app, similar to yours where I am changing date format:

The transform - `app/transforms/utc.js`:

```
import DS from "ember-data";
import moment from 'moment';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function (value) {
        return moment.utc(value);
    }
});
```

And my model - `app/models/day.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    year: DS.attr('number'),
    date: DS.attr('utc'),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    dateSlug: Ember.computed('date', function() {
        return moment(this.get('date')).format('MM-DD');
    })
});
```